# Writing dataframe to csv WITHOUT removing commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to write a pandas dataframe to csv.  One of the columns of the df has entries which are lists, e.g. [1, 2], [3, 4], ...

When I use df.to_csv('output.csv') and I open the output csv file, the commas are gone.  That is, the corresponding column of the csv has entries [1  2], [3  4], ....

Is there a way to write a dataframe to csv without removing the commas in these lists?  I've also tried using csv.writer.

Comment: Use the `sep` argument to `to_csv` e.g. `pd.DataFrame.to_csv(sep='\t')` would separate with tabs not commas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add keyword argument `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

data = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [[11,12],[21,22],[31,32]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.name='index'

# df
#        A         B
# index             
# 0      1  [11, 12]
# 1      2  [21, 22]
# 2      3  [31, 32]

df.to_csv('test.csv',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

## Output:

```
"index","A","B"
"0","1","[11, 12]"
"1","2","[21, 22]"
"2","3","[31, 32]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Sadly, this also isn't working for me; don't know why.

Comment: I have a feeling the culprit is your `DataFrame`.  `sep='\t' and my solution should both work.  Heck, even WITHOUT either of these `to_csv()` should automatically quote items with commas in it.  Perhaps post a sample of your `DataFrame` and code for more details

Comment: You were right.  The "lists" [1,2], [3,4], etc turned out to be numpy arrays instead.

Comment: Good suggestion (it adds quotes) but for me it still does not include commas when the original data is a `np.array`.  The solution was to convert the values in my dataframe to lists and the commas are retained during `to_csv` even without `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`df.to_csv('output.tsv', sep='\t')`

Will separate the values with tabs instead of commas.

.tsv is tab separated value file

Comment: Unfortunately, the commas are still disappearing.  Do you have any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed commas in my csv file, too. So, I tried to get it using df but in vain. I decided to do the following.
I read tap-separated text file, first, and write to a csv file with commas added.
Not sure this is what you exactly want, but this way you can have commas in your csv file. Hope it helps.

```
with open('test.txt', newline = '') as cos:
    co_reader = csv.reader(cos, delimiter='\t')
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        cowriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for co in cog_reader:
        cowriter.writerow(co)
```